# Requisição da API retorna vazia em classe mapeada

Tags: api, http, dart, flutter

Estou com um problema ao tentar retornar a resposta de uma ***api*** na minha ***classe***. Quando tento executar a minha lista retorna ***null*** ao invés dos dados da api

***Minha classe Foto***

```
class Foto {

  final int AlbumId;
  final int Id;
  final String Titulo;
  final String Url;
  final String Thumb;

  Foto({this.AlbumId, this.Id, this.Titulo, this.Url, this.Thumb});

  factory Foto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return new Foto(
      AlbumId: json["albumId"],
      Id: json["id"],
      Titulo: json["title"],
      Url: json["url"],
      Thumb: json["thumbnailUrl"]
    );
  }

}
```

***Minha classe de Requisição***

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:meu_app/models/Foto.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:meu_app/models/Usuario.dart';

class Http {

  get(String url) async {

    http.Response response = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
    decode(response);
  }

  decode(http.Response response){

    if(response.statusCode == 200){

      var decoded = jsonDecode(response.body);

      List<Foto> fotos = decoded.map<Foto>((fotos){
        return Foto.fromJson(fotos);
      }).toList();

      print(fotos);

      return fotos;

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz umas modificações no seu exemplo, segue elas:

**main.dart**

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<Foto> _fotos;
  Api _api = Api();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getFotos();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: _fotos == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _fotos.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Foto foto = _fotos[index];

                  return ListTile (
                    title: Text("${foto.titulo}"),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage("${foto.url}"),
                    ),
                  );
                }
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  void getFotos() async {
    _fotos = await _api.get();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

**foto.dart**

```dart
class Foto {

  final int albumId;
  final int id;
  final String titulo;
  final String url;
  final String thumb;

  Foto({this.albumId, this.id, this.titulo, this.url, this.thumb});

  factory Foto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Foto(
        albumId: json["albumId"],
        id: json["id"],
        titulo: json["title"],
        url: json["url"],
        thumb: json["thumbnailUrl"]
    );
  }

}
```

**requisicao.dart**

```dart
class Api {

  Future<List<Foto>> get() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
    return decode(response);
  }

  List<Foto> decode(http.Response response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decoded = jsonDecode(response.body);

      List<Foto> fotos = decoded.map<Foto>((fotos) {
        return Foto.fromJson(fotos);
      }).toList();

      print(fotos);
      return fotos;
    }
  }

}
```

**Resultado**

[image: GIF]

Bom, o seu request e decode funcionaram corretamente, o problema é que você está trabalhando com a api de Future e async de forma errada, você não está informando o retorno, lembre-se que em um método assíncrono quando o Dart chega na linha que contém `await`, ele já retorna um resultado para quem chamou o método. É necessário informar então como retorno um `Future`, que nada mais é do que uma promessa, dizendo que em algum momento do futuro esse `Future` irá possuir um valor concreto dessa requisição. [Para saber mais](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

Alguns pontos extras:

- Não use nome das variáveis iniciando como letra maiúscula, isso não é uma boa prática, conforme consta [na documentação](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase):

> Class members, top-level definitions, variables, parameters, and named
>   parameters should capitalize the first letter of each word except the
>   first word, and use no separators.

- Não utilize o new para criação de objetos, a partir da versão 2 do Dart essa keyword se tornou opcional, ou seja, é uma boa prática não utilizá-la tendo em vista que o código fica mais 'clean'.
- Procure sempre anotar o retorno dos seus métodos com o tipo retornado (ao invés de dynamic), isso facilita a vida do compilador e otimiza a detecção de possíveis erros.
- Aconselho não tratar o decode do json de forma manual, a não ser que seja para aprendizado apenas, caso contrário, recomendo trabalhar com [geração de código](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#use-code-generation-for-medium-to-large-projects)
- Esses conceitos iniciais e um exemplo completo muito parecido com o que você tá fazendo tem [nesse artigo aqui](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/n%C3%A3o-use-drogas-use-flutter-talk-2-671ad7c19c30) (ou [nesse GitHub](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/flutter_talk)).

Comment: vlw, não só pela respostas mas também pelos toques.